# How to authenticate to GeoNode API v2?

Tags: geonode

I am creating a geonode-project app and I want to authenticate to the GeoNode API v2, but I cannot find an endpoint to authenticate. I listed all endpoint of the API using http://localhost:8000/api/v2/ but I cannot find and endpoint to authenticate. How can I authenticate to the GeoNode REST API?

Answer (score 2):

The API accepts a BasicAuth header (with your credentials) or a Bearer token. A token is generated when you signin through the UI. You will see it's sent with any API request executed by GeoNode's UI.

The generated token has an expiration date (24h). If you are an Administrator you can extend its lifetime. You can locatw and modify the token under /admin/oauth2_provider/accesstoken/